# Why are the chartjs tooltip labels always showing the first x-axis label?

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

The chartjs default tooltips seem to be displaying data incorrectly. No matter which datapoint I hover over, the tooltip label always shows "Week of Jan 24th".

I expected it to show "Week of Jan 31st" when hover over the "Week of Jan 31st" data points and "Last Week" when hovering over the "Last Week" data points. Am I wrong on this?

[image] 
[image]

Comment: can you provide a fiddle which reproduces this error?

Comment: I'll see what I can do Quince, but I think it has something to do with dynamically changing x-axis labels...I think I need to call update() or something similar. I have a toggle for different data ranges: Quarters, Months, Weeks and Days so the x-axis values change when the user clicks those. If I hard-code the labels the tooltips are fine.

Comment: I confirmed that that was indeed the problem. I'm using react-chartjs from npm so I had to set the redraw property to true on the <LineChart /> component

Comment: The drawback to this approach is that the lines drop to zero then animate to their new position. Without the redraw the lines animate from their current position to the new position, which looks a lot nicer

Comment: any luck on this issue? I have the same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LineChart data={this.state.yourData} options={this.state.yourOptions} redraw="true"/>
```

**redraw="true"**